# Call to a member function bind_result

Tags: php, mysqli

i got an error in

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean

then if i delete the `$stmt->execute();` other error occurs

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_result() on boolean

:(

```
$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to Connect" .mysqli_connect_errno();
    die();
    }
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, customer_id, first_name, last_name, middle_name, path_to_photo_thumbnail FROM customers;");
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($id, $customer_id, $first_name, $last_name, $middle_name, $path_to_photo_thumbnail);

$cutomer = array();

while($stmt->fetch()){
    $temp = array();
    $temp['id'] = $id;
    $temp['customer_id'] = $customer_id;
    $temp['first_name'] = $first_name;
    $temp['last_name'] = $last_name;
    $temp['middle_name'] = $middle_name;
    $temp['path_to_photo_thumbnail'] = $path_to_photo_thumbnail;
    array_push($cutomer, $temp);
}
echo json_encode($cutomer)
```

Comment: Don't mix procedural and OOP. Use `$conn->connect_errno` instead of `mysqli_connect_errno()`. This may not be the answer to your question but still it isn't a good practice. Also, whenever you get a boolean `false` on `prepare()`, you can assume that something is wrong with your query.

Comment: i already got it bro thanks.. now the problem is not display is should display a json but it returns empty

Comment: ok, does `var_dump($stmt->fetch())` return true? Probably the `while` condition isn't true, hence you are getting an empty json.

Comment: `prepare()` is failing and thus, returning a boolean (`false`). Add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script and try again. The error will be reported as an exception

Comment: $query = "SELECT id, first_name, last_name, middle_name, path_to_photo_thumbnail 
              FROM customers";
    
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
   $array = array();
 while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
     $array[] = json_encode($r);
   }

   echo json_encode($array); ill try this one it works but the json output was incorrect format the output was ["{\"id\":\"1\",\"first_name\":\"Maricar\",\"last_name\":\"Nator\",\"middle_name\":\"\",\"path_to_photo_thumbnail\":

Answer (score 0):

replace `customers;` with `customers` in your sql statement.

Comment: done bro fixed it.. my problem now is to display it via json

Comment: I've never seen a semi-colon suffix on a query produce an error before. Have you tested this?

Comment: yes. i never ; in prepare. i don't know much but prepare adds ; itself